# Where is the flaw in my algorithm for finding the size of the maximum connected region of 1s in an array of 0s and 1s?

Tags: c#, algorithm

For example, if the array is like

```
1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
```

then the answer is `5`.

I have a helper function

```
// Returns the size of the region of 1s containing the point (x0, y0). 
// For example, if mat = 0 0 1
//                       1 0 0
//                       1 1 1
// then max_connected_region(0,0,mat) = 0, 
//      max_connected_region(2,0,mat) = 1,
//  and max_connected_region(0,1,mat) = 4
static int max_connected_region(int x0, int y0, int[,] mat)
{  
    if(mat[x0,y0] == 0)
        return 0;
    var surroundings = (new int[][] {
        new int[] { x0 - 1, y0 }, new int[] {x0 + 1, y0 }, 
        new int[] { x0 - 1, y0 + 1}, new int[] { x0, y0 + 1 }, new int[] {x0 + 1, y0 + 1},
        new int[] { x0 - 1, y0 - 1}, new int[] { x0, y0 - 1 }, new int[] {x0 + 1, y0 - 1} }
     ).Where(pair => pair[0] >= 0 && pair[0] < mat.GetLength(0) && pair[1] >= 0 && pair[1] < mat.GetLength(1));
    int count = 1;
    foreach(var pair in surroundings)
        count += max_connected_region(pair[0], pair[1], mat);
    mat[x0,y0] = 0;
    return count;
}
```

and how I find the maximum connection in an `n x m` array (`n` rows, `m` columns) is using it like

```
   int max_connections = 0;
   for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i)  
       {
           if(matrix[i,j] == 0)
               continue;
           int connections = max_connected_region(i,j,matrix);
           if(connections > max_connections)
               max_connections = connections;
       }
   }
```

This procedure is giving me either a timeout or an out-of-bounds in the test cases and I can't figure out why.

Comment: How it be `5`? what is the logic you are trying to apply

Comment: @un-lucky Think of it as the alrgest island of `1`s.

Comment: Can you explain how your algorithm is supposed to work?

Comment: Ah, I see.. Looks like unbounded recursion to me. You check a cell's neighbours, then recursively check *their* neighbours, one of which is the original cell, of course..

Comment: not really answering ur question, but better approach instead of recursion is to build the graph, where a node is a consecutive cells of `1`s in a row. Two nodes are connected if they are on consecutive rows and there is a cell belonging to same column. The weight of the edge is the number of cells in both nodes. So the graph is actually is a collection of trees and u need to find one with maximum sum of edges.

Comment: Don't expect us to determine _what it is what your program is meant to do_, especially when it is an implementation of an _algorithm_ that isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071218/where-is-the-flaw-in-my-algorithm-for-finding-the-size-of-the-maximum-connected#comment65490788_39071218), your algorithm is revisiting array elements it's already checked, putting it in an endless loop.

You actually have a program statement that appears to be trying to avoid this, but you execute it *after* your recursive call. So it has no useful effect. If you simply move it before the loop that performs the recursive calls, your algorithm will work:

```
static int max_connected_region(int x0, int y0, int[,] mat)
{
    if (mat[x0, y0] == 0)
        return 0;
    var surroundings = (new int[][] {
        new int[] { x0 - 1, y0 }, new int[] {x0 + 1, y0 }, 
        new int[] { x0 - 1, y0 + 1}, new int[] { x0, y0 + 1 }, new int[] {x0 + 1, y0 + 1},
        new int[] { x0 - 1, y0 - 1}, new int[] { x0, y0 - 1 }, new int[] {x0 + 1, y0 - 1} }
     ).Where(pair => pair[0] >= 0 && pair[0] < mat.GetLength(0) && pair[1] >= 0 && pair[1] < mat.GetLength(1));
    int count = 1;
    mat[x0, y0] = 0;
    foreach (var pair in surroundings)
        count += max_connected_region(pair[0], pair[1], mat);
    return count;
}
```

I note that your algorithm is destructive. That is, it modifies the array that's passed to it. This may be acceptable for your scenario — at worst, it means the caller needs to make sure that it passes a copy of its data. But if this were to be some sort of library method, you might consider making the copy yourself, or using an appropriately-sized `bool[,]` to track where the algorithm has already visited.

I also feel that allocating a whole new array for the `surroundings` with each iteration of the method is maybe not the best approach. If you intend to run this algorithm on much larger data sets, it might make more sense to have a static array containing the valid offsets, and then just have an explicit `for` loop iterating through that array for the recursive calls. This will minimize the extra memory allocation and garbage collection overhead as you visit each array element.

Making those changes, the method, and its supporting class members, would look more like this:

```
static int max_connected_region2(int x0, int y0, int[,] mat)
{
    return max_connected_region2_impl(x0, y0, (int[,])mat.Clone());
}

static int max_connected_region2_impl(int x0, int y0, int[,] mat)
{
    if (mat[x0, y0] == 0)
        return 0;

    int count = 1;

    mat[x0, y0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < adjacentCells.Length; i++)
    {
        int[] pair = adjacentCells[i];
        int x1 = pair[0] + x0, y1 = pair[1] + y0;

        if (x1 >= 0 && x1 < mat.GetLength(0) && y1 >= 0 && y1 < mat.GetLength(1))
        {
            count += max_connected_region2_impl(x1, y1, mat);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static readonly int[][] adjacentCells =
{
    new [] { -1, 0 }, new [] { 1, 0 }, new [] { -1, 1 }, new [] {0, 1 },
    new [] { 1, 1 }, new [] { -1, -1}, new [] { 0, -1 }, new [] { 1, -1 }
};
```